# How to round down number 2 decimal places?

Tags: javascript

How to get following inputs to bellow outputs

Input

```
1.0789
10.350
1.7777
```

Output

```
1.07
10.35
1.77
```

Comment: `after=Math.floor(before*100)/100`

Comment: `1.7777` to `1.77` is NOT round down. It's truncation. Is truncation what you really need?

Comment: This is not a duplication of the linked question. It specifically asks about rounding *down*, whereas the linked question covers rounding *off*.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use `Math.floor` to round the decimal places under the current value.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)

**Example**

```
Math.floor(1.0789 * 100) / 100
```

**Working Fiddle**

```js
console.log(Math.floor(1.0789 * 100) / 100);
console.log(Math.floor(10.350 * 100) / 100);
console.log(Math.floor(1.7777 * 100) / 100);
console.log(Math.floor(12.34 * 100) / 100);
```

Comment: it's not a round down

Comment: If you are looking for under rounding. you need to use Math.floor

Comment: Thanks. Its works dude..

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: This does not work for values like 12.34 which are already 2 decimal places. 12.34 will turn into 12.33. A better solution `function floorDecimals(value, decimals) {
  return Number(Math.floor(value+'e'+decimals)+'e-'+decimals);
}`
 Credit goes to here http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/

Comment: @SeanTomlins The simple solution with multiply / divide seems to work for flooring and ceiling in Chrome and Firefox, for me at least.

Comment: @SeanTomlins note: this will not work with typescript.

Comment: @FiddleFreak Typescript compiles to javascript, why will it not work?

Comment: @SeanTomlins `Math.floor(3.29012 + 'e' + 3)` typescript error - "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'."

Comment: @SeanTomlins Are you sure that this solution breaks for value `12.34`. I tested this solution with latest chrome, edge and IE. It still works as expected for me.

Comment: Note that `Math.floor` **always** goes **down** the number scale, which may or may not be what you want with negative numbers. For instance, `Math.floor(-1.0789 * 100) / 100` returns `-1.08`. For rounding toward zero, you have to branch: `result = value < 0 ? Math.ceil(value) : Math.floor(value)`.

Comment: I found an example that breaks the original solution:
`console.log(4222.11 * 100);` is `422210.99999999994`
so it incorrectly returns `4222.10`
but the exponential notation method avoids this bug.

Answer (score 1):

you have several methods for do this

1. Use **Math.round(num * 100) / 100**
2. Use **Math.ceil(num * 100)/100;**

Comment: The 3 methods you propose are rounding the decimals up. But the question was how to round them down.

Comment: `toFixed` is rounding them down.

Comment: `toFixed` rounds up for 5 and above, only round down when 4 and less

Comment: `toFixed` returns a string.